# Get the latest record and the previous record prior to that

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need help on how to optimize my code.  What I want here is to select the latest schedule year and previous schedule year prior to that. Assuming also that if ScheduleYear 2019 is not available. The script will still get 2018, 2017.

```
select ScheduleYear
from t_year 
where (getutcdate() between yearbegin and yearend OR datepart(yy,getutcdate()) = ScheduleYear
OR ScheduleYear = (SELECT ScheduleYear-1 FROM t_year WHERE getutcdate() between yearbegin and yearend)))
and enabled = 1
order by ScheduleYear DESC
```

Comment: i update the script to include columns to be filtered by getutcdate()

Comment: what is this yearbegin and yearend?

Comment: columns in t_year , can be any date  but the yearend is always greater than yearbegin  for the same record.

Comment: so these are actual columns?

Comment: yes. ScheduleYear,yearbegin ,yearend  are columns in t_year

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for  `order by` and `top`?

```
select top (2) ScheduleYear 
from t_year 
where 
     ScheduleYear <= year(getutcdate()) 
    and enabled = 1
order by ScheduleYear DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the needed results with top and an appropriate sort:

```
SELECT TOP 2 
   ScheduleYear 
FROM t_year 
WHERE enabled = 1
ORDER BY ScheduleYear DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to achieve.

```
select top 2 coalesce(ScheduleYear, year(getutcdate())) as ScheduleYear from t_year 
where (ScheduleYear between yearbegin and yearend
    or
        year(getutcdate()) between yearbegin and yearend)
and enabled = 1
order by coalesce(ScheduleYear, year(getutcdate())) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ScheduleYear` is unique, you can use:

```
select top (2) ScheduleYear
from t_year 
where getutcdate() >= yearbegin and enabled = 1
order by ScheduleYear desc;
```

If you have duplicates, then use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct top (2) ScheduleYear
from t_year 
where getutcdate() >= yearbegin and enabled = 1
order by ScheduleYear desc;
```

Don't use `select distinct` unless necessary, because it adds processing overhead.